# new to android: why must class extend activity to pass its context

Tags: java, android

there is a class called Utils:

```
public class Utils{  }
```

There is another class called HotOrNot. It's contains a constructor like this:

```
public HotOrNot(Context c){ ourContext =c ;}
```

In the utils class, I want to start an instance of HotOrNot so I type this:

```
HotOrNot info = new HotOrNot(this);
```

but, this code gives me the following error:

> The constructor HotOrNot(Utils) is undefined

I resolved this error by extending Utils class like this:

```
public class Utils extends Activity {   }
```

why must Utils extend activity in order to pass its context HotOrNot's constructor?

Comment: because Activity extends the class Context and Utils does not

Comment: Your question doesn't make much sense. Let's say HotOrNot is a Car, whose constructor needs a Driver. You can't pass an Apple to the Car's constructor, because an apple is not a Driver. Of course you can make Apple extend Driver, to pretend it is a Driver and be able to pass it to the Car constructor. But although it will compile, I doubt it does something useful.

Comment: You should probably work through a Java tutorial. Just extending `Activity` solves the compile error, but it will not work.

Comment: you can pass the activity context to the constructor of utils class Note Do not keep long-lived references to a context-activity (a reference to an activity should have the same life cycle as the activity itself)

Answer (score 1):

The constructor of `HotOrNot` expects a `Context` (usally this would be your main activity).
So just passing `this` in the Util class won't work (because it is not a subclass of `Context`)
Instead of extending `Activity` in your Utils class, you should somehow pass a reference to your `Activity` to Utils so you can use it there.

Comment: how do you  pass a reference to  Activity as you are suggesting ?

Comment: @lisagreen `new Utils(ActivityName.this)` then Utils class `COntext mCOntext;` Then  `public Utils(Context context){ mCOntext = context;}`

Comment: @lisagreen now use mCOntext as new HotOrNot(mContext);